# How to set default value to getdate() with sql server

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm using the sequel ruby orm with sql server.
I would like to know how to set the default value of a datetime field to the sql server function getdate() in a migration:

```
create_table(:table) do
  primary_key :id
  datetime :last_update, null: false, default: ???
end
```

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `default: Sequel.function(:getdate)`, assuming you are a using the current version of Sequel.